# How to populate row values in dynamically generated column datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How could I go about populating the rows with unique values in each column

My xaml

```
<DataGrid Width="500" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding tests}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="TemplateColumn" x:Shared="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding lol}"></TextBlock>
                            <!--<local:SampleUserControl />-->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

My Code

```
        private void CreateDataGridColumns()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Change number of columns here.
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn =
                  (DataGridTemplateColumn)dataGrid.Resources["TemplateColumn"];
            templateColumn.Header = String.Format("Test {0}", i + 1);
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            _mainViewModel.tests.Add(
                new test { lol = "testing " + j }
                );
        }
    }
```

Just in case it matter my viewmodel , the datagrid is bound to this tests

```
    internal class mainViewModel
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<workerViewItem> workerViewItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<workArea> workAreas { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<test> tests { get; set; }
}
```

And the class

```
    internal class test
{
    public string lol { get; set; }
}
```

Current result
[image]

and for context i am trying to create something similar to this app
[image]

Comment: It might actually be cheaper than writing this to buy a set of controls which offer closer behaviour than a datagrid straight out the box.  Telerik offer controls like the radscheduleview for example. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radscheduleview/overview

Comment: I worked on a suite which had a scheduling control in it. This was a custom control which took forever to build and was a constant maintenance headache.

Comment: Slight issue with that, this is my internship task and my bachelors work+ the company doesnt want to spend money, they want their in house programmers to do the work

Comment: Ha... well I think you might be busy for a while on this then. Good luck!

Comment: You dont inspire confidence xD, but thanks

Comment: Andy check out my solution, might not be the most slick, but I think it will serve me well

Answer (score 0):

After extra testing I have come to the conclusion that for my use case the correct tool was user controls generated in stackpanels

```
            UserControl1 item;

        StackPanel panelo;
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            panelo = new StackPanel();
            panelo.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {

                item = new UserControl1(k + i);

                panelo.Children.Add(item);
            }
            panel.Children.Add(panelo);
        }
```

All the logic will be done inside the template for the UserControl
[image]

```
        public UserControl1(int lol)
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
        boxuy.Text = lol.ToString();
    }
```